Transposing dataset with repeated / incomplete observations in R
I have the following dataset:
Pt_ID   vital_descr vital_value 
1   HR  70  
1   SBP 110 
1   DBP 75  
1   HR  NA
1   SBP 105
1   DBP 60
2   SBP 150
2   DBP 90
3   HR  55
3   SBP 150 
3   DBP 70  
3   SBP 160
3   DBP 70
3   SBP 160
3   DBP 80

And I want to "transpose" it to this:
Pt_ID   HR_1    SBP_1   DBP_1   HR_2    SBP_2   DBP_2   HR_3    SBP_3   DBP_3
1   70  110 75  NA  105 60  NA  NA  NA
2   NA  150 90  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
3   55  150 70  NA  160 70  NA  170 80

In the original dataset, the value of each vital sign is reported in a distinct row; the type of vital sign is identified by the "vital_descr" column. For every patient, the same vital sign might have been reported from zero to multiple times.
I would like to have the final dataset to have a number of rows that equals the number of patients and all the observations transposed to columns named according to the corresponding "vital_descr" label; repeated observations should be reported in separate columns identified with appropriate suffixes and not aggregated.
I have tried with reshape2 and with dcast but this is a bit more than I can deal with.
Thank you.

Using dcast() from data.table:
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, dcast(.SD, Pt_ID ~ paste(vital_descr, rowid(Pt_ID, vital_descr), sep = "_"))]

#    Pt_ID DBP_1 DBP_2 DBP_3  HR_1  HR_2 SBP_1 SBP_2 SBP_3
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1    75    60    NA    70    NA   110   105    NA
# 2:     2    90    NA    NA    NA    NA   150    NA    NA
# 3:     3    70    70    80    55    NA   150   160   160

Data:
df <- data.frame(
  Pt_ID       = rep(1:3,c(6,2,7)),
  vital_descr = c("HR","SBP","DBP","HR","SBP","DBP","SBP","DBP","HR","SBP","DBP","SBP","DBP","SBP","DBP"),
  vital_value = c(70,110,75,NA,105,60,150,90,55,150,70,160,70,160,80)
)


There may be a more elegant way to do it entirely within pivot_wider itself, but a practical way could be to use dplyr::mutate to add the instance number for each value in the vital_descr column, and then pivot_wider:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(vital_descr = paste0(vital_descr, "_", row_number()),
         .by = vital_descr) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = vital_descr, values_from = vital_value)

Output:
#   Pt_ID  HR_1 SBP_1 DBP_1  HR_2 SBP_2 DBP_2 SBP_3 DBP_3  HR_3 SBP_4 DBP_4 SBP_5 DBP_5 SBP_6 DBP_6
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1    70   110    75    NA   105    60    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2     2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   150    90    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 3     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    55   150    70   160    70   160    80

Data:
df <- read.table(text = "Pt_ID   vital_descr vital_value 
1   HR  70  
1   SBP 110 
1   DBP 75  
1   HR  NA
1   SBP 105
1   DBP 60
2   SBP 150
2   DBP 90
3   HR  55
3   SBP 150 
3   DBP 70  
3   SBP 160
3   DBP 70
3   SBP 160
3   DBP 80", h = TRUE)

